# I've made a slight mistake in my .htaccess and now i cannot access my page anymore

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, raspberry-pi3, nextcloud

To be more specific, i changed my php_value memory_limit accidently to 20GB while i was changing the maximum upload and post sizes. I changed it back to what it was 512MB but my page is still giving me a HTTP ERROR 500.

Anyone got any ideas what i'm missing?

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
       SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" XAUTHORIZATION=$1
       RequestHeader set XAuthorization %{XAUTHORIZATION}e env=XAUTHORIZATION
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_proxy_fcgi.c>
       SetEnvIfNoCase Authorization "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    # Add security and privacy related headers
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "none"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-Download-Options "noopen"
    Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies "none"
    SetEnv modHeadersAvailable true
  </IfModule>

  # Add cache control for CSS and JS files
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 5G
  php_value post_max_size 5G
  php_value memory_limit 512MB
  php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
  php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
  php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
  php_value output_buffering 0
  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv htaccessWorking true
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 5G
  php_value post_max_size 5G
  php_value memory_limit 512MB
  php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
  php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
  php_value output_buffering 0
  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnv htaccessWorking true
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/dav/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates)/.* - [R=404,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*
```

This is my error log

```
[Sun Sep 10 16:37:08.095999 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 634:tid 1974465584] [client 212.238.239.196:56997] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /var/www/nextcloud/lib/composer/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412\n'
[Sun Sep 10 16:38:14.788907 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 632:tid 1995735040] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Sep 10 16:38:15.055829 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1218:tid 1995862016] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 10 16:38:15.153908 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1219:tid 1995862016] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 10 16:38:15.159375 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1219:tid 1995862016] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) OpenSSL/1.0.2l configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 10 16:38:15.159570 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1219:tid 1995862016] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Sep 10 16:38:16.044752 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1223:tid 1974465584] [client 212.238.239.196:57043] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  **Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes)** in /var/www/nextcloud/lib/composer/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 412\n'
```

Any help would be appreciated to the max

Answer (score 2):

Your htaccess file is invalid. You are starting the directive `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` but never closing it using `</IfModule>`.

I would advice to download the default htaccess file shipped by nextcloud and try again. Just download the zip file from here: https://nextcloud.com/install/#instructions-server and replace the htacess file.

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess settings are only used for PHP executed within that folder or sub folders - [What is the difference between php.ini and .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138830/what-is-the-difference-between-php-ini-and-htaccess)

Looking at the error message (`Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted`) suggests that composer has a much lower memory limit than what you set so my guess would be that it is not affected by your htaccess.

Try setting the limit in your php.ini file instead.

Comment: I think that error happened when the TS tried to set the `memory_limit` to 20G. 2097152bytes is 2GB and not the 512MB he has now set in the htaccess file.

Comment: @LEDfan 2097152 bytes are 2 mebibytes exactly. That said though, you are right - if it isn't a copy paste omission then the missing closing tag would cause an issue.